# Constantly respawning in the middle of the goblin army!

Tags: terraria

So I just started hardmode and the Goblin army caught me completely by surprise. Summoners showed up that I have never faced before. My spawn is in the center of the map where my NPC's *were*. I am now constantly respawning now in the middle of the army and they kill me most every time. My items are not far but I can't move fast enough before the apparitions, summoners and wizards kill me.

I'm pretty sure the answer is "You're screwed" and I have to exit the game losing all my good loot (that is one the ground) that I just got from defeating the Wall of Flesh.

Is there something I can do to get out of this that won't risk my items? I took my hellavator and the army went away but when I died, since I could not survive the fall, the army returned.

My current play is I am hoping to walk enough away from my items that I can then attempt a dash, once I respawn, in the other direction to get most of my items and then quickly exit.

I am playing on medium core so just keep killing them is not a good option since copper short sword sucks on a good day.

Answer (score 2):

While this might not be practical or possible in all situations I was able to get through this in about an hour after *dying a lot*.

Since I was located inside my base my stored items were in close vicinity. Enemies would follow me and in a general sense be drawn to my location of death as well. I would move my character, 20-30 squares when I was lucky, away from my base to give me a little lead time ahead of some of the goblins. This proved useless against the wizards but after a few tries I gained enough time to get to a chest in the opposite direction.

However I only had time to remove one ... sometimes two at a time. I selected a flail and a yoyo on a separate occasion. Trick at this point was to move as little as possible with the exception of jump dodging. I would get in a hit or two before I died.

Now when I would re-spawn I would instantly be equipped with a weapon which usually occupied the same slot. Sometime I would pick us spike balls so that death would accomplish nothing. Many deaths were for not and I could not get any hits in either due to knockback or appearing in front of projectiles.

After a long period of working like this the army was defeated and the summoner eventually de-spawned and did not need to be killed. (Would only have been a matter of time before she perished before my infinite lives though)

In the end I lost nothing but some time in my actual life.

Answer (score 0):

You respawn with a pickaxe right? You could slowly attempt to dig a hole under or near your spawn point. Once you get a bit of dirt you can make walls surrounding yourself that will protect from all mobs except for the sorcerer's projectiles, but those can be destroyed by hitting them with the pickaxe.

Comment: That tactic will be ineffective vs the goblin summoner. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Summoner

Answer (score -3):

## Just kill them.

Really. You don't lose anything accept for coins, which you easily regain. If you have killed the WOF, then you should have a couple of good ranged weapons to 1-shot the goblins.

Don't you have rocket boots? Use them to your advantage. Escape the army and fly somewhere safe.

<strike>EDIT: Make a new world, get a whole bunch of stuff that is easy to get like Light's bane (demonite), or Fiery Greatsword (Hellstone), and One shot them.</strike>

If you keep on attacking with the sword they give you, then EVNTUALLY you will kill the wave off. Just keep respawning and dying, and eventually you can kill them off. Heck, just get one of your friends to do it with you!

Comment: He isn't playing on the difficulty where you lose only coins, that's the problem.

Comment: He also doesn't want to leave the game because he'll lose all his items on the ground.